# use expression tree to evaluate properties of a generic class

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

i have to evaluate a formula which contains certain expressions, say for eg:"column1 * column3". These column names are dynamic and are generated only at run time. I have the class objects with me having these column names.
The expressions can have any basic arithmetic operators.

I think this could be approached with Expression tree in c#. Would that be the best approach. If so could someone provide me some assistance on how to approach this because i could not find any good examples on Expression trees. Or whether it could/should be done using reflections.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That really depends, if it is not performance critical code, you are much better off with reflection, the source code will be easier to read and maintain.